# Extra Lines using SyntaxHighlighter for Chrome Only?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, blogger, syntaxhighlighter

Extra lines are being inserted when I am using Chrome to look at a draft blog post (on blogger) that uses syntax highlighter e.g.

[image: Chrome extra lines inserted]

But on IE it looks fine:

[image: IE looks fine]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

edit:

The config/setup for SyntaxHighlighter I am using is below:

```
<!-- Syntax Highlighter Additions START -->
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushcsharp.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
<!-- Syntax Highlighter Additions END -->
```

edit:

And the HTML generated is:

```
<pre class="brush: csharp;">using System;
<br />using System.Text;
<br />using System.Collections.Generic;
<br />using System.Linq;
<br />using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
<br />using AccountTypeFollowUp;
<br />
<br />namespace PluginsUnitTests
<br />{
<br />    [TestClass]
<br />    public class AccountTypeFollowUpTests
<br />    {
<br />        [TestMethod]
<br />        public void AccountTypeFollowUp_Account_Is_Supplier()
<br />        {
<br />            throw new NotImplementedException();
<br />        }
<br />
<br />        [TestMethod]
<br />        public void AccountTypeFollowUp_Account_Is_Client()
<br />        {
<br />            throw new NotImplementedException();
<br />        }
<br />
<br />        [TestMethod]
<br />        public void AccountTypeFollowUp_Account_Is_Other)
<br />        {
<br />            throw new NotImplementedException();
<br />        }
<br />    }
<br />}
<br /></pre>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Having the same problem; it appears to be caused by this section of the shCore.css file:

```
.syntaxhighlighter table td.gutter .line {
  text-align: right !important;
  padding: 0 0.5em 0 1em !important;
}
```

If I replace the 'padding' with:

```
padding: 0 5px  !important;
```

The numbering works properly in Chrome (without negatively affecting Firefox and IE displays) so for now I have my blog pointing to a customized shCore.css rather than http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css

Comment: Yeah I found that if I pointed to the 2.1 version, it was fixed too. I shall try the customised version, thanks!

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem with chrome

Comment: Customised script ^^ worked for me. Also, if you prefer, link to the 2.1 version and it works across FF, IE and Chrome for me

Comment: I've had trouble finding a place to host the custom CSS file. SkyDrive and DropBox links didn't work well for me. Anyone have a link to the 2.1 version of this file?

Comment: @atconway I have edited the CSS file as jane said and hosted here 
http://codeoncloud.co.cc/shCore.css This may helpful to you

Comment: While this did improve the line numbering, I still have problems with the longest lines having their last characters wrapped to the next line, screwing up the line-numbering at the bottom of the code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Paste before `<pre class="brush: js;">`

```
<style>
    .syntaxhighlighter table td.gutter .line {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reference a different CSS file. Paste the following style block *after* the link tag that references shCore.css:

```
<style>
  .syntaxhighlighter table td.gutter .line {
    padding: 0 5px !important;
  }
  .syntaxhighlighter table td.code .line {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .syntaxhighlighter .gutter {
    padding-right: 1em !important;
  }
  .syntaxhighlighter table {
    padding-bottom: 1px !important;
  }
</style>
```

`.syntaxhighlighter table td.gutter .line` adds 5 pixels of horizontal padding around each line number.

`.syntaxhighlighter table td.code .line` removes all padding from the line of code itself.

`.syntaxhighlighter .gutter` adds 1 em of padding between the gutter and the line of code.

`.syntaxhighlighter table` solves an overflow problem I was seeing with Chrome. For code blocks that overflowed horizontally, Chrome was rendering a vertical scrollbar that could be scrolled 1 pixel. Adding 1 pixel of padding to the table inside the container div fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of these solutions to work. However, a comment in [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140868) gave me the solution...

Opened the template editor (editing html), and searched for '13px'. There were two instances near the variable definitions. I updated the font size to 12px, and everything worked.

```
     <Variable name="body.font" description="Font" type="font"
     default="normal normal **12px** Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal normal **12px** Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue with blogger.com and latest Firefox.
I found that it happens because of overlapping styles on class `.container`, so basically you have to rename class to something like `.containerSH` in SyntaxHighlighter.
See my [commit: change .container -> .containerSH](https://github.com/dsatsura/syntaxhighlighter/commit/9e77c6f943b8b9d8c3ff17f41bb339efead4e84c) 
 Now it works ok for me.